# Visual Studio Tools for Office - Multiple accesses to the same gmail account with multiple Outlook 2013-2016

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, gmail, vsto, outlook-addin

I need to access the same gmail account with Outlook, through several different machines.
But **gmail blocks multiple simultaneous connections** after a certain amount of connections.
I did research and found nothing in relation to this scenario.
I thought about creating a service to centralize sending and receiving to gmail, and synchronizing Outlook with this service.
I think this management can be complex.
In regards to receiving emails, I'm thinking of creating an add-in with **Visual Studio for Office** to consume the service and insert the new messages into Outlook programmatically.
Has anyone gone through this scenario or do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

VSTO (nor Outlook COM add-ins) will not help in this case. At least you need to develop a custom store provider (Extended MAPI) like it was implemented in [G Suite Sync for Microsoft Outlook](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync). Have you tried installing and running this add-in? Does it help?

Comment: If I try to synchronize the same account on multiple machines, it stops working at any given time.

Comment: With the add-in installed?

Comment: Yes, installed.